# How to fix Symfony2 deployment issues?

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.7

I'm having this issue for a while at differents environments, differents projects and some times I did fixed some others likes now I can't find what is failing so this is my latest try.

I want to deploy a app so following rules as [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html) say the first I did was:

```
composer install --optimize-autoloader
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
Clearing the cache for the dev environment with debug true
Trying to install assets as symbolic links.
Installing assets for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle into web/bundles/framework
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sonata\CoreBundle into web/bundles/sonatacore
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sonata\AdminBundle into web/bundles/sonataadmin
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Nelmio\ApiDocBundle into web/bundles/nelmioapidoc
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for PDI\TemplateBundle into web/bundles/template
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
Installing assets for Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle into web/bundles/sensiodistribution
The assets were installed using symbolic links.
```

Second and because I miss to update composer libraries I re-run composer update command:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Removing symfony/symfony (v2.6.9)
  - Installing symfony/symfony (v2.7.0)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Removing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.25)
  - Installing sensio/distribution-bundle (v3.0.28)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing yriveiro/php-fslock (0.1)
    Downloading: 100%

  - Installing jordillonch/deploy-bundle (dev-master 3f8e679)
    Cloning 3f8e679eb2ac87d0cef9ea9dd4765afd24c6a266

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
Updating the "app/config/parameters.yml" file
PHP Deprecated:  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryMethod(getEntityManager) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead. in /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php on line 137
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/console:0
PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/console:27
PHP   3. Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->boot() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Console/Application.php:70
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->initializeContainer() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2396
PHP   6. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->compile() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache:2618
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\Compiler->compile() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerBuilder.php:614
PHP   8. Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/Compiler.php:117
PHP   9. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\MergeExtensionConfigurationPass->process() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/DependencyInjection/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:39
PHP  10. Sonata\DoctrineORMAdminBundle\DependencyInjection\SonataDoctrineORMAdminExtension->load() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Compiler/MergeExtensionConfigurationPass.php:55
PHP  11. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->load() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle/DependencyInjection/SonataDoctrineORMAdminExtension.php:44
PHP  12. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseDefinitions() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:58
PHP  13. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader->parseDefinition() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:119
PHP  14. Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition->setFactoryMethod() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Loader/XmlFileLoader.php:153
PHP  15. trigger_error() /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php:137
PHP Deprecated:  Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition::setFactoryService(doctrine) is deprecated since version 2.6 and will be removed in 3.0. Use Definition::setFactory() instead. in /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/Definition.php on line 208
```

And I got a lot of warnings but go to next step. Try to call a prod URL (without `app_dev.php`) and got this:

```
[2015-06-02 09:43:11] request.INFO: Matched route "api_1_post_emails". {"route_parameters":{"_controller":"PDI\\PDOneRestBundle\\Controller\\TargetRestController::postEmailsAction","_format":"json","_route":"api_1_post_emails"},"request_uri":"http://api.dev.pdone.com/api/v1/emails?_format=json"} []
[2015-06-02 09:43:11] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token. [] []
[2015-06-02 09:43:11] security.INFO: No expression found; abstaining from voting. [] []
[2015-06-02 09:43:11] php.CRITICAL: Fatal Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PDIPDOneBundleEntityTerritory.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') {"type":64,"file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php","line":209,"level":6143,"stack":[{"function":"getProxyDefinition","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\AbstractProxyFactory","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php","line":119,"args":[]},{"function":"getProxy","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\Common\\Proxy\\AbstractProxyFactory","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php","line":2677,"args":[]},{"function":"createEntity","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\UnitOfWork","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php","line":138,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateRowData","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\SimpleObjectHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/SimpleObjectHydrator.php","line":48,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateAllData","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\SimpleObjectHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Internal/Hydration/AbstractHydrator.php","line":140,"args":[]},{"function":"hydrateAll","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Internal\\Hydration\\AbstractHydrator","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Persisters/BasicEntityPersister.php","line":756,"args":[]},{"function":"load","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\Persisters\\BasicEntityPersister","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php","line":411,"args":[]},{"function":"find","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityManager","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php","line":154,"args":[]},{"function":"find","type":"->","class":"Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityRepository","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/src/PDI/PDOneRestBundle/Controller/TargetRestController.php","line":224,"args":[]},{"function":"postEmailsAction","type":"->","class":"PDI\\PDOneRestBundle\\Controller\\TargetRestController","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3094,"args":[]},{"function":"call_user_func_array:{/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache:3094}","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3094,"args":[]},{"function":"handleRaw","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3056,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\HttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":3207,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\DependencyInjection\\ContainerAwareHttpKernel","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/bootstrap.php.cache","line":2429,"args":[]},{"function":"handle","type":"->","class":"Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Kernel","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/web/app.php","line":27,"args":[]},{"function":"{main}","file":"/var/www/html/pdone_backend/web/app.php","line":0,"args":[]}]} []
[2015-06-02 09:43:11] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: "Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PDIPDOneBundleEntityTerritory.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php')" at /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php line 209 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException(code: 0): Compile Error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/pdone_backend/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies/__CG__PDIPDOneBundleEntityTerritory.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') at /var/www/html/pdone_backend/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/AbstractProxyFactory.php:209)"} []
```

How I can fix that issue? What is the cause of this? I have clear cache by hand, running Symfony commands, I have restarted web server (Apache) several times and nothing seems to help. Any advice?

Comment: Random anwser, have you tried `composer install --no-dev --optimize-autoloader`?

Comment: @smarber Yes, but what if I want to keep dev libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a permission issue (failed to open ...) so from within the project directory do

```
chmod 777 -R app/cache
```